# A puzzling result of the `ReplaceAll`

Tags: replacement, rule

I tried to do something below

```
Log[PDF[NormalDistribution[m, s], x]] /. Log[u_[x__] ] :> Plus @@ Log[List[x]]
```

which gives a desirable result that splits the expression into pieces.
Note that `PDF[NormalDistribution[m, s], x]` was evaluated of the form `Times[a,b,c]` and thus `u` was identified as `Times`.

However, if I replace `u_` by `Times`, i.e.,

```
Log[PDF[NormalDistribution[m, s], x]] /. Log[Times[x__] ] :> Plus @@ Log[List[x]]
```

then, I got an unexpected result that does not change the expression. Can you explain why I should not use `Times` even though I know that `u_` will match `Times` in the first example?

Comment: Take a look at `HoldPattern`. `Times[x__]` is evaluated.

Comment: @Kuba I don't think I understand you. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Kuba is actually pretty specific.

```
In[1]:= Log[PDF[NormalDistribution[m, s], x]] /. 
 HoldPattern[Log[Times[x__]]] :> Plus @@ Log[List[x]]

Out[1]= Log[E^(-((-m + x)^2/(2 s^2)))] - 1/2 Log[2 \[Pi]] + Log[1/s]
```

BTW, you may also interested in `PowerExpand`.